# How to use workmanager as an upload service

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am building an offline first chat app and so I'm using `Workmanager` to handle `POST` requests to send chat messages.

I'm learning android development and so I wanted some help on architecturing the upload of chat messages

#### Current implementation

When ever a new chat message needs to be posted the client does the following

1. Saves the chat to SQLite using Room with a new UUID
2. Starts a workmanager `unique work` to POST this message
3. This way I can be sure the message is posted eventually when the client has internet

Is this ideal? There are a few issues I see.

1. I'm starting too many workers. Each message has a work request.
2. Chronology of messages posted to the server is lost.

##### A better implementation

1. A single unique worker to POST messages. Which will fetch all offline messages and post them in the right order

#### Still not ideal

The issues with these implementation are:

1. You have very little control on a work (not so easy) once it's started.

   - If a work fails we've set a backoff time. So when a new message is to be sent we need to replace the old worker with the new work request. This just seems nonoptimal.

   > We are mutating the worker instead of appending a new task to the queue.

   - We can't use the one worker per message implementation because we loose chronology and there are too many workers

#### This is sort of a distributed systems question.

- We are starting workers who should work independ of the lifetime of the app
- Workers should come back alive in a case they die (already managed by `android-workmanager`)
- Workers should read from a queue of task to be executed (which is what I'm looking for)
- There should be a persistance store that acts as a queue for the workers
- There should be a service or a factory that invokes workers when ever needed (We don't have this in the current impl)

#### Questions

1. Is there a better way to post offline messages to the server when the client has internet? Like a service?
2. Is there a community build library that does this?
3. Can the current implementation be scaled to files?

   - I would need [long running workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running)
   - Or could use this lib - [android-upload-service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service)

Comment: you can use workmanager, but you need a key in room db isSent - false. If nets get connected hit post requrests through work manager or Services (a/c to your wish) but when you get success then please update isSent - true, so it cannot be sent again when connection established

Comment: @DeePanShu Yes I'm already doing that. And I've already implemented "a single worker to do all POSTs" too. But my question if there was a better way. I'll make changes to the question to why I think the current implementation is not satisfying.

Comment: @clmno Which language are you using? This is needed so I can post the answer in that language.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I'm using Kotlin but I don't think this depends on the language. Its an android subsystem question.

Comment: @clmno a/c to my knowledge, I don't think there is a satisfying implementation because the best optimization is always a realtime frameworks, when we are implementing chatting in our app.

Comment: @DeePanShu Whats a real time framework in an android context?

Comment: XMPP servers, Firebase realtime database, Firestore database etc. are all real-time

Comment: @DeePanShu I'm using websockets. But the question is for when the app is offline and a chat message is created.

Comment: @clmno When you are using websockets, then why you need separate threads to post messages, is your websockets to posting your messages after connections gain.

Comment: @DeePanShu But I want to sync the messages even when the app is "not alive". This is how WhatsApp works. It doesn't wait for the app to be opened. It simply sync the message when ever it has network access.

Comment: @DeePanShu I guess I came to the realization I could start a workmanager that starts the websocket service. Wait for sync to complete and the end the worker. But here I would need to register a worker when ever a POST fails. But I think this is good. I'm just concerned its a custom solution. Asking if people have implemented something already.

Comment: @clmno ok great

Comment: @clamentjohn Hi, would you mind sharing some insight as to how you solved your problem ? I think I've got a similar use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043038/how-do-i-sync-a-room-database-with-an-sql-server) where I need to upload data at the first opportunity (and ensure data gets sent when coming back online)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Service to effectively sync the messages, First create an Object which will extend from Live Data Class to get live updates for network updates like this,

```
object NetworkState : LiveData<Boolean>() {

private lateinit var application: Application
private lateinit var networkRequest: NetworkRequest
private lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager

fun init(application: Application) {
    this.application = application
    connectivityManager = application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .build()
}

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    getDetails()
}

private fun getDetails() {

    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            postValue(true)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            postValue(false)
        }

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable()
            postValue(false)
        }
    })
}
```

Then initialize this in your Application class like this,

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    NetworkState.init(this)
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }
}
}
```

Now you can create a Service class which will extend from Lifecycle Service and observe the Network updated there. And when the Live Data will emit value true you can check if there are messages which needs to be synced online. But remember it will only work when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Looks good. But this is for when the app is "alive". I'm using a websocket service that observes the network state and syncs messages. But my question was for workmanagers and offline message syning when the app isn't event opened.

Comment: This is actually good. I should impl this for my websocket service. But again, what when the app is closed but there are still messages or files to be sent. Think WhatsApp like offline syncing.

Comment: Use Periodic Work Manager for that.